# Unable to read from Kerberised HBase

Tags: hbase, kerberos

While connecting to remote HBase cluster, I can create Table and get Table Listing.  But unable to scan Table using Java API. Below is code

```
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",     "QUARAM");
configuration.set("hbase.master", "MASTER");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
configuration.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
configuration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-secure");
configuration.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
configuration.set("hbase.rpc.protection", "authentication"); 
configuration.set("hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal", "hbase/Principal@realm"); 
configuration.set("hbase.regionserver.keytab.file", "/home/developers/Desktop/hbase.service.keytab3"); 
configuration.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal", "hbase/HbasePrincipal@realm"); 
configuration.set("hbase.master.keytab.file", "/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab");

System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","/etc/krb5.conf");

String principal = System.getProperty("kerberosPrincipal", "hbase/HbasePrincipal@realm");
String keytabLocation = System.getProperty("kerberosKeytab", "/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab");
UserGroupInformation.set    configuration(    configuration);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keytabLocation);
UserGroupInformation userGroupInformation = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("hbase/HbasePrincipal@realm", "/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab");
UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(userGroupInformation);
```

I am getting bellow errors,

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions: Mon Jul 09 18:45:57 IST 2018, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=64965: row '' on table 'DEMO_TABLE' at region=DEMO_TABLE,,1529819280641.40f0e7dc4159937619da237915be8b11., hostname=dn1-devup.mstorm.com,60020,1531051433899, seqNum=526190

Exception : java.io.IOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
```

Comment: Have you set caching in your scan object like scan.setCaching()? It it is set to default, try to lower the value and check.

Comment: Yes, it is a default. But my question is it works when I remove Kerberos else it won't

Comment: @iamLalit I am facing the exact same issue with kerberized Hbase. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No, it's not. I am still in search.

Comment: @RCkumar Do we have any solution on this?